# Quickly parse large utf-8 text file in haskell

Tags: parsing, haskell, utf-8

I have a 300MB file ([link](http://dumps.wikimedia.org/other/pagecounts-raw/2011/2011-11/pagecounts-20111117-010000.gz)) with utf-8 characters in it. I want to write a haskell program equivalent to:

```
cat bigfile.txt | grep "^en " | wc -l
```

This runs in 2.6s on my system.

Right now, I'm reading the file as a normal String (readFile), and have this:

```
main = do
    contents <- readFile "bigfile.txt"
    putStrLn $ show $ length $ lines contents
```

After a couple seconds I get this error:

```
Dictionary.hs: bigfile.txt: hGetContents: invalid argument (Illegal byte sequence)
```

I assume I need to use something more utf-8 friendly? How can I make it both fast, and utf-8 compatible? I read about Data.ByteString.Lazy for speed, but Real World Haskell says it doesn't support utf-8.

Comment: `grep -c "^en " bigfile.txt` is faster. That out of the way, the invalid byte sequence error says that the file isn't valid utf-8 or your file handle isn't set to utf-8. If your ghc is recent, it will by default read files in the locale encoding, check that. If it's not utf-8, `hSetEncoding stdin utf8` ought to fix it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Package [utf8-string](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/utf8-string) provides support for reading and writing UTF8 Strings. It reuses the `ByteString` infrastructure so the interface is likely to be very similar.

Another Unicode strings project which is likely to be related to the above and is also inspired by ByteStrings is discussed in [this Masters thesis](http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/files/3929/dissertation.pdf).

Comment: I feel stupid asking this, but how do I read a file as a lazy utf8 string? Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 has a readFile method, but Data.ByteString.Lazy.UTF8 doesn't.

Comment: @SeanClarkHess: See [System.IO.UTF8.readFile](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/utf8-string/latest/doc/html/System-IO-UTF8.html#v:readFile).

Comment: Ah, you use Data.ByteString.Lazy.readFile, then call Data.ByteString.Lazy.UTF8's function on the ByteString. Thanks!

Comment: @hammar - no that doesn't work, because it reads it into a String. Data.ByteString.Lazy.readFile works though

Comment: @SeanClarkHess: Ah, I thought that was what you wanted. Anyway, for your particular use case, you should be able to ignore the encoding altogether, since you're only comparing against characters in ASCII range, and UTF-8 never contains ASCII-range bytes as part of a multi-byte character.

Comment: Interesting.  This (utf8-string) is horribly slow.  If I replace the obvious filter test `((== "en") . UTF.take 2)` with `... BSLazy.take 2` then I get from 2x the speed of the shell script to tied (i.e. skipping UTF decoding is a win).  More surprising though, making the accumulator of `UTF8.splitAt` strict gives a measurable win.  Marking `decode` as inlinable and we get closer still.  I guess I'll submit a patch.

Comment: [Pull request away](https://github.com/glguy/utf8-string/pull/4): I now get 1.2 seconds in Haskell via this utf8-string package (vs 1 second for the above shell scriptory).

Comment: The `System.IO.UTF8`, which contained functions like `readFile`, was removed from utf8-string [when it got to version 1](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/utf8-string-1).